# Measuring time volume with times in multiple columns

Tags: r, time

I am working with data that records the start time and end time of an interaction. My goal is to measure the volume at specific intervals of time (e.g. 12:00, 12:30, 13:00). My goal is essentially to do a logical check to see if a time range, in this case an hour block, fits inside a time range represented by two columns. The data looks like this

```
client       start_time     end_time
smith          08:00          10:15
coven          09:30          10:25
peter          07:35          11:30


The result I would like would look like this

time         count
07:00          0
07:30          1
08:00          2
08:30          2
09:00          2
09:30          3
10:00          3
10:30          1
11:00          1
11:30          1
```

I know I could do it by hand in Excel but there are a couple thousand rows and I'd like it to be reproducible. I've googled quite a lot and I can't find an answer. I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction

My first thought was to build out the columns really wide by using mutate. I converted the times into integers to make working with them a bit easier for me. This would work, but very slowly and at the end I'd still need to find a way to fill in the missing times in the middle.

I've thought of using within, but I don't see if I can apply it here.

Here is the code as it stands.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(eight_ = ifelse(start_num >= 480 & start_num <= 539 | end_num >= 480 & end_num <= 539 , 1, 0))
```

The code works as expected, It puts a 1 in the correct column for start and stop. The problem is I don't know how to fill in the middle columns which currently would receive zeros.

Comment: This `if a time range, in this case an hour block, fits inside a time range represented by two columns` is unclear. Are you saying that you want to check whether `end_time - start_time` is greater than one hour? Or, possibly, if 8:00AM falls between `start_time` and `end_time`? Can you clarify?

Comment: And where does your `time` column come from? Are you defining 30 minute blocks, or are these blocks coming from your data?

Comment: And finally, your example using `df1` and `start_num/end_num` seems to have no bearing on the first half of your question. What is `df1`? Where do `start_num/end_num` come from?

Comment: 1. It's if 8:00 AM falls between start_time and end_time

Comment: 2. The time column is just a representation of the desired final product. It was included to give the reader a better understanding of where I was trying to get

Comment: 3. As I mentioned in the post, I converted the times into integers to make working with them easier. i don't know if thats the best path, that's just the one I went down. df1 is the dataset that is mentioned in the post that includes names and the start and end times of interactions

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there must be a much easier way to achieve it, but here is my solution using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(client) %>%
 do(data.frame(time = seq(as.POSIXct(.$start_time, format = "%H:%M"),
               as.POSIXct(.$end_time, format = "%H:%M"), by = "min"),
               temp = 0)) %>%
 complete(time = seq(as.POSIXct("07:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"),
                     as.POSIXct("11:30:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"), by = "min")) %>%
 mutate(time = round_date(time, unit = "30minutes")) %>%
 group_by(client, time) %>%
 summarise(temp = ifelse(any(temp == 0), 1, 0)) %>%
 group_by(time) %>%
 summarise(count = sum(temp, na.rm = TRUE))

   time                count
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2019-01-22 07:00:00    0.
 2 2019-01-22 07:30:00    1.
 3 2019-01-22 08:00:00    2.
 4 2019-01-22 08:30:00    2.
 5 2019-01-22 09:00:00    2.
 6 2019-01-22 09:30:00    3.
 7 2019-01-22 10:00:00    3.
 8 2019-01-22 10:30:00    3.
 9 2019-01-22 11:00:00    1.
10 2019-01-22 11:30:00    1.
```

First, it is expanding the original df for every client by minutely sequence from "start_time" to "end_time". For all minutes a zero in "temp" variable is assigned. Second, by using `complete()`, it creates a minutely sequence that has a specified starting and end point. Therefore, clients who have no data in some parts of the given time sequence will have NA on the "temp" variable, otherwise 0. Third, using `round_date()`, it rounds the times in "time" variable to 30 minutes. Forth, it groups by "client" and "time" and assess whether there is any 0 in "temp". If so, it assigns 1, otherwise 0. Finally, it groups by "time" and returns the sum of ones, indicating an occurrence in that given time interval.

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "client       start_time     end_time
smith          08:00          10:15
coven          09:30          10:25
peter          07:35          11:30", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is but I can't get seq() to work, nothing but errors.

Comment: Is it working on the sample data I provided in my post?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that expands `start_time` and `end_time` by `30 minute` intervals and tallies the the result.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(
  client = c("smith", "coven", "peter"),
  start_time = c("08:00", "09:30", "07:35"),
  end_time = c("10:15", "10:25", "11:30")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    start_time = floor_date(as.POSIXct(start_time, format = '%H:%M', tz = 'UTC'), unit = '10 minutes'),
    end_time = floor_date(as.POSIXct(end_time, format = '%H:%M', tz = 'UTC'), unit = '10 minutes'),
  ) %>%
  nest(start_time, end_time) %>%
  mutate(time = map(data, ~seq(unique(.x$start_time), unique(.x$end_time), unit = 'min', by = '30 min'))) %>%
  unnest(time) %>% 
  mutate(time = format(time, '%H:%M')) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  tally()

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  time      n
  <chr> <int>
1 07:30     1
2 08:00     2
3 08:30     2
4 09:00     2
5 09:30     3
6 10:00     3
7 10:30     1
8 11:00     1
9 11:30     1
```

If you need to have the full time interval from `07:00 to 11:30` you can do the following:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    start_time = floor_date(as.POSIXct(start_time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"), unit = "10 minutes"),
    end_time = floor_date(as.POSIXct(end_time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"), unit = "10 minutes"),
  ) %>%
  nest(start_time, end_time) %>%
  mutate(time = map(data, ~ seq(unique(.x$start_time), unique(.x$end_time), unit = 'min', by = '30 min'))) %>%
  unnest(time) %>%
  mutate(time = format(time, "%H:%M")) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  tally() %>% 
  right_join( # add full sequence of time intervals
    tibble(time = seq(
      as.POSIXct("07:00", format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"),
      as.POSIXct("11:30", format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"), 
      unit = 'min', by = '30 min'
    )) %>%
      mutate(time = format(time, "%H:%M")),
    by = 'time'
  )

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   time      n
   <chr> <int>
 1 07:00    NA
 2 07:30     1
 3 08:00     2
 4 08:30     2
 5 09:00     2
 6 09:30     3
 7 10:00     3
 8 10:30     1
 9 11:00     1
10 11:30     1
```